# rufus-scheduler -> not a valid cronline on Windows

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler

I have simple rufus code that works on GNU/Linux but not on Windows.

I am using the same version of rufus. Just updated Ruby on Windows to `ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [i386-mingw32]` but it did not help.

**Question:** Any idea if `.cron` supposed to work on Windows?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new


scheduler.cron '0 22 * * 1-5' do
  # every day of the week at 22:00 (10pm)
  puts 'activate security system'
end

scheduler.every '5m' do
  puts 'check blood pressure'
end
```

error received

```
D:/prog/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.4/lib/rufus/scheduler/cronline.rb:61:in `initialize': not a valid cronline : '0 22 * * 1-5' (ArgumentError)
from D:/prog/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.4/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:601:in `new'
from D:/prog/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.4/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:601:in `initialize'
from D:/prog/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:630:in `new'
from D:/prog/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:630:in `do_schedule'
from D:/prog/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.1.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:245:in `cron'
from test.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Yes, cron is supposed to work on Windows as well. Could you please paste the detailed and complete error message that you get? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jmettraux: I thought that it should work on Windows. Error added.

Comment: Yes, cron is supposed to work on Windows as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the problem.

I have opened an issue at https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/issues/166

**UPDATE**

Issue fixed, [rufus-scheduler 3.1.5](https://rubygems.org/gems/rufus-scheduler/versions/3.1.5) released.

Should there be any further problems, please fill a new, detailed, issue at https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/issues